# Calling Rest service with json return, issue in chrome

Tags: json, wcf, rest, google-chrome

I have a Rest service which if I execute it in IE or Firefox it executes fine.
http://MyPC.com/Services/REST.svc/Work/Lists?$format=json

But when I try to execute it in Chrome I just get this error.

http://MyPC.com/Services/REST.svc/Work/Lists?$format=json:1 GET http://MyPC.com/Services/REST.svc/Work/Lists?$format=json net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Has anyone experienced this before and find a way to resolve it.
I've played around with the bindings in the config with no success

Just a note, I tried another Rest Service which I wasn't hosting and it worked in both IE and Chrome.
So it doesn't look like the issue is with Chrome.

I just want to add I didn't write any of these services, I'm still figuring it all out

Answer (score 0):

Seems it sending the windows credentials through in binding did the trick, Chrome for some reason throws a connection issue when it didn't have the credentials for the service where as IE and Firefox seem to sk for the credentials when its required